# Is this a left join or right join, inner or outer?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

Sitting here at work writing SQL for the first time in a while. I know all the vendiagrams of all the joins, but I was wondering what type of join I just wrote. Is this even a typical join since I'm not using a 'JOIN' keyword?

```
select * from table1 t, table2 a where a.column1 = -10300 AND t.column1 = a.column2;
```

Thanks,
k9

Comment: Looks like an inner join

Comment: Just a comment on the title. Left and right joins are both outer joins. I'm not making assumptions but it's not clear whether you recognized that.

Comment: Yet another reason to use explicit joins and not implicit. They are out of style for more than 20 years now, and with a lot of good reasons.

Answer (score 2):

This performs the same as an inner join because of the "t.column1 = a.column2". If that was left out, it would be a cross apply.

Here's some more info: http://explainextended.com/2009/07/16/inner-join-vs-cross-apply/

Answer (score 0):

Its Inner join as you used Inner Join logic in Where.

Comment: This is incorrect. Tables can still be joined without actually using the join statement.

Comment: @HandyPete , Updated. Just was not focussing on question.

Comment: The point remains. It's still a join, just syntactically different.

Comment: It says that is is not syntactically a join. But it is, just an less explicit syntax.

Comment: I did, so get rid of the first.

Comment: @HandyPete , yes did ! Happy now ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what would be considered an older style inner join.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL writing `JOIN` unqualified implies `INNER JOIN`. In other words the `INNER` in `INNER JOIN` is optional.
Official documentation about JOIN [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old oracle-style inner join.  It will give you all rows from both tables where the column matches, which is pretty much what an inner join is.

FYI, this used to be standard practice in Oracle SQL before everything went to ANSI-standard SQL.